# Leaflet map has incorrect dimensions within Django template blocks

Tags: django, django-templates, leaflet

I am using a leaflet map on a website and I am trying to use the template blocks within Django to have a more flexible webpage design whilst keeping common elements. However, when I attempted to implement this, my leaflet map changed dimensions for no apparent reason. The code is the same except it is now within template blocks.

This is what the site should look like (Ignore the grey background, it's just due to the scrolling screenshot)
[image: What the page should look like]
This is what it looks like with the template blocks
[image: What the page looks like]

Here is the [Github](https://github.com/MaxMichel2/PWEB/tree/master/exchange/templates/exchange) of the project. The correct look of the webpage is the `accueil.html` file and the new version is based on `base.html` and `accueil_base.html`.

I haven't been able to determine what is causing the dimensions issue. Even when I inspect the map element, all the map components are there, only the dimensions are modified.

My apologies regarding the lack of code in this post (I felt it would make this question much longer than needed). I also feel you may have issues recreating my problem since you don't have a database with the corresponding points.

Thanks in advance and please tell me if you need any precise information regarding my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the issue I had was that I forgot to implement the `<style>` of the map container which is as follows

```
<style>
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>
```

The `#map` element is inserted into a block that is definer just before the `<head>` tag in the base.html file. Since this is all on Github, you should easily be able to see the changes.